# How to set two breakpoints in one line in Chrome developer tools?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, internet-explorer, developer-tools

Trying to debug some JavaScript. In Internet Explorer (you know, that browser everybody loves?) it is very easy to set two breakpoints in one line. Let's say the line is like this in the HTML source:

```
<script type="text/javascript">function something() {alert("foo");}</script><script type="text/javascript">function somethingelse() {alert("bar");}</script>
```

In IE I could either just right click > set breakpoint or click in both alerts and hit <kbd>F9</kbd>. The debugger then steps into both breakpoints.

In Chrome I cannot do such a thing. There is no right mouse button > set breakpoint and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> always sets/removes the breakpoint for the whole line. In the breakpoints panel on the right I can see the breakpoints have cols, but there is no manual way to edit these (even though I wouldn't want to figure out the cols by counting).

Don't I know how to Chrome or is it just not possible in Chrome to have multiple breakpoints in one line?

Comment: You could maybe use the "pretty-print" button. [Link](https://plus.google.com/+AddyOsmani/posts/Q7t2U51G7YR)

Answer (score 4):

Use the `Pretty print` button to prettify JS code. Then apply breakpoints on separate lines.

Here's a demonstration:
[image: Chrome Developer Tools - Pretty Print button]

Comment: that's what I was thinking, should have mentioned in the OP that pretty print doesn't work with all documents (I guess malformed etc.). In your simple example it works. In my source pretty print doesn't change a single line in the HTML.

Comment: I used the same code you mentioned in your question. You forgot a `"` after the second `<script type="text/javascript>` which is why it isn't working for you. Change it to `<script type="text/javascript">` and you're done.

Comment: Yes you did. As you can tell it is example not production code.

Comment: @DennisG I tried using this solution on this page itself. It was able to prettify minified jquery.js and other scripts as well. However, if it doesn't work for you, maybe [this link](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging) would help?